# Awk calculation for overtime pay

Tags: function, unix, awk

For the following data, I am trying to determine what the over time total would be using an awk file. 
(Overtime rule: if more than 40 hours worked, each hour after gets 1.5 times salary)

```
Natlie Attired 902-555-1234 10.40 44 
Guy Wyre 401-555-3421 11.75 40
```

This is what I have so far

```
BEGIN{
     FS=" "
}
function total(){
    hours = awk {print $5}
    rate = awk {print $4}
    if(hours<=40)
        sum=rate*hours
        return sum
    else
        sum=(hours - 40 * 1.5 * rate) + (rate*hours)
        return sum
}

{
    printf("%s %s worked %d hours, for a total pay of %.2f.\n", $1, $2,$5, total())
}
```

What do I need to change in order for this to produce an accurate answer?

Comment: You don't really need the `BEGIN` block; the default field separator is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

To make it execute without errors, I had to:

- remove the `awk {print ...}` surrounding `$5` and `$4`
- add braces to the if-then-else statement

To make the calculation correct, I had to:

- put parentheses around `hours - 40`
- replace `1.5` by `0.5` (or alternatively, replace `(rate * hours)` by `(rate * 40)`)

Resulting code:

```
function total() {
    hours = $5;
    rate = $4;
    if (hours <= 40) {
        sum = rate * hours;
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        sum = ((hours - 40) * 0.5 * rate) + (rate * hours);
        return sum;
    }
}

{
    printf("%s %s worked %d hours, for a total pay of %.2f.\n", $1, $2, $5, total());
}
```

Output:

```
Natlie Attired worked 44 hours, for a total pay of 478.40.
Guy Wyre worked 40 hours, for a total pay of 470.00.
```

Comment: The parentheses are required because of [operator precedence](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Precedence.html#Precedence): `*` has a higher precedence than `-`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function total(     regHours, otHours, rate, sum){
    rate = $4
    regHours = $5
    if (regHours > 40) {
        otHours = regHours - 40
        regHours = 40
    }
    sum = ((otHours * 1.5) + regHours) * rate
    return sum
}

{
    printf "%s %s worked %d hours, for a total pay of %.2f.\n", $1, $2, $5, total()
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Natlie Attired worked 44 hours, for a total pay of 478.40.
Guy Wyre worked 40 hours, for a total pay of 470.00.
```

Comment: quick tutorial on awk functions: you localize function variables by adding them to the parameter list. By convention, separate the function arguments from the local variables by some whitespace. http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax